# Java String indexOf that ignores duplicate characters

Tags: java, string, char, character, indexof

I need a version of java.lang.String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex) that ignores duplicate characters as in it returns the index of the first single occurrence of a letter.

This differs from the indexOf method the String class because it requires the string to be just   a single instance of the string, so if the string appears two or more time consecutively, it will not return any of those values. If there is not single instance, the method should return -1 like the normal indexOf.

For an example we will call the method indexOfNoDup:

```
static String string = "aabaccbdd";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    indexOfNoDup("a", 0);
    //Output: 3
    //The first single occurrence of "a" is in position 3. The "a"s in position 0 and 1 are not returned because they are not single instances.

    indexOfNoDup("b", 4);
    //Output: 6
    //The first single occurrence of "b" at or after position 4 is in position 6.

    indexOfNoDup("c", 0);
    //Output: -1
    //There is no single instance of "c" in the line.

    indexOfNoDup("a", 1);
    //Output: 1
    //The first single occurrence of "a" at or after position 1 is in position 1.
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for ? Duplicates or no duplicates , indexOf returns the index of first occurance of the string or it returns -1 if the string is absent

Comment: consider this code: `"aabacccbdd".indexOfNoDup("cc", 0);` what is the expected output?

Comment: TheQuickBrownFox 4, but I really only care about single characters.

Comment: Moh123, no duplicates. It should return the index of first lone occurrence of the string or it returns -1 if there is no lone occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to model your problem first. We can model this with a finite state machine.

[image]

<sup>Image created with [draw.io](http://draw.io)</sup>

So what we want to do is to implement that state machine. There are a couple ways of doing so. Here's one such way (assuming I implemented it right, but this shouldn't be too hard to debug):

```
int index = -1;
int state = 0;
while (index < string.length()) {
    int new_index = string.indexOf(value, index + 1);
    if (new_index == -1) {
        switch (state) {
            case 0: return -1;
            case 1: return index;
            case 2: return -1;
        }
    }
    if (new_index == index + value.length()) {
        if (state < 2) state++;
    } else {
        state = 0;
    }
    index = new_index;
}
```

For the specific case of single characters, we can do it like this:

```
int index = -1;
int found_index = -1;
int state = 0;
while (index < string.length()) {
    if (string.charAt(index + 1) == value) { //assuming value is type char, else do value.charAt(0)
        if (state < 2) state++;
        if (state == 1) found_index = index;
    } else {
        state = 0;
    }
    index++;
}
switch (state) {
    case 0: return -1;
    case 1: return found_index;
    case 2: return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below is dirty, but passed your requirement. Refactoring and further testing is left to you.

```
private static int indexOfNoDup(String str, char c, int start) {
    char[] array = str.toCharArray();
    int length = array.length;
    if (start < 0 || start >= length) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if (start == length - 1 && array[start] == c) {
        return start;
    }
    for (int i = start; i < length; i++) {
        while (i < length - 1 && array[i] == c && array[i + 1] == c)
            i = i + 2;
        }
        if (array[i] == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code will be:

```
int indexOfNoDup(string aChar, int startPosition){
  int posInString; // character position in static String "string"
  int lenString;   // length of static String "string"
  int pos;         // temporal

  for (posInString=startPosition, posInString<lenString; posInString)
    {
       if (aChar == string[posInStrings])
         {
           if ((posInString+1<lenString) && (aChar == String[posInStrings+1])) { // followed by same  character
               if(posInString+2<lenString){
                 return -1; // no more characters after successive charecters.
               } else {
                 for (pos = posInString+2; (pos < lenString) && (aChar == string[pos]); pos++)
                   ; // skip successive characers.
                 posInString = pos; // character at posInString is other character or end of string.
               }
             } else {  // found isolated character!
               return posInStrings;
             }
         }
    }
}
```